# Layout depending on number of elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment, css-grid

I have a wrapper that can contain 2, 3 or 4 elements (I don't know it in advance because every element renders itself, depending on API response).

If there are 3 (or less) I want them to stack like:

[image: 3 elements layout]

No big deal. But when there are 4 of them, I need this other layout:

[image: 4 elements layout]

So far, I thought CSS Grid would be the way to go and I tried:

```js
/* Just to add some interaction to the demo */

const w = document.getElementById("wrapper");
let x;

function toggle(event) {

  const d = document.getElementById("D");
  return d 
    ? 
      x = d.cloneNode() && w.removeChild(d) 
    : w.appendChild(x);
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}



.item {
  grid-column-start: span 2
}

.item:nth-last-child(1),
.item:nth-last-child(2) {
  grid-column-start: auto;
}


/* Non-relevant CSS here: */

button {
  margin: 20px auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

#A { background: #7984f7 }
#B { background: #cb8af8 }
#C { background: #8cd4fb }
#D { background: #97f8d8 }

.item {
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="A" class="item">A</div>
  <div id="B" class="item">B</div>
  <div id="C" class="item">C</div>
  <div id="D" class="item">D</div>
</div>

<button onclick="toggle()">Click me!</button>
```

But it doesn't work for 3 elements... In fact, I've tried many things (all CSS Grid related) and there's probably an easier solution I can't see right now... Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CSS grid:

1. display all items in two columns by default
2. display items 1 and 2 in a single column
3. display item 3 in a single column only if it's the last item

One side effect is that if there are ever more than 4 items, the additional ones will display in two columns.

```js
/* Just to add some interaction to the demo */

const w = document.getElementById("wrapper");
let x;

function toggle(event) {

  const d = document.getElementById("D");
  return d 
    ? 
      x = d.cloneNode() && w.removeChild(d) 
    : w.appendChild(x);
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}



.item {
  grid-column-start: auto;
}

.item:nth-child(1),
.item:nth-child(2),
.item:nth-child(3):last-child {
  grid-column-start: span 2;
}


/* Non-relevant CSS here: */

button {
  margin: 20px auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

#A { background: #7984f7 }
#B { background: #cb8af8 }
#C { background: #8cd4fb }
#D { background: #97f8d8 }

.item {
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="A" class="item">A</div>
  <div id="B" class="item">B</div>
  <div id="C" class="item">C</div>
  <div id="D" class="item">D</div>
</div>

<button onclick="toggle()">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using flexbox. For the given three possibilities use this simple css in the snippet below.

Basically you make the items appear in a row but with wrapping if they don't fit. You make the first two elements take all width so that there is only one per row. And for the 3rd and 4th you set their flex-basis (initial width) to something smaller and make them grow (flex-grow: 1) if there is space.

```css
.examples{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.container{
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.box{
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  flex-basis: 200px;
}
.box:nth-child(3), .box:nth-child(4){
  flex-basis: 50px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="examples">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Solution also here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jym7v5nh/1/)

Comment: Answers are even better when you don't have to go to another site to see them in action. Consider using [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to embed a runnable snippet here on Stack Overflow. Note that you can click on the Copy snippet to answer button to make it even easier.

Comment: Good call, @HereticMonkey . I added the snippet - thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

You can select the *elements after the third child* using `:nth-child(n+4)` and *elements after the second child* by using `:nth-child(n+3)` and conjure up:

```
.item:nth-child(n+4):nth-last-child(1),
.item:nth-child(n+3):nth-last-child(2) {
  grid-column-start: auto;
}
```

Now you have the grid configuration you'd searched for - this will work for *any* number of `item` elements - see demo below:

```js
/* Just to add some interaction to the demo */
const w = document.getElementById("wrapper");
let x;
function toggle(event) {
  const d = document.getElementById("D");
  return d ?
    x = d.cloneNode() && w.removeChild(d) :
    w.appendChild(x);
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
.item {
  grid-column-start: span 2;
}
/* CHANGED THIS */
.item:nth-child(n+4):nth-last-child(1),
.item:nth-child(n+3):nth-last-child(2) {
  grid-column-start: auto;
}
/* Non-relevant CSS here: */
button {
  margin: 20px auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
#A {
  background: #7984f7
}
#B {
  background: #cb8af8
}
#C {
  background: #8cd4fb
}
#D {
  background: #97f8d8
}
.item {
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="A" class="item">A</div>
  <div id="B" class="item">B</div>
  <div id="C" class="item">C</div>
  <div id="D" class="item">D</div>
</div>
<button onclick="toggle()">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a trick that works.

The 3rd child that is ALSO 2nd from last, AND the 4th child will have grid-column-start set to auto.

```
.item:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(2),
.item:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column-start: auto;
}
```

With a small tweak if you want ALL children from 4th position up to be split across two columns.

```
.item:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(2),
.item:nth-child(n+4) {
  grid-column-start: auto;
}
```

```js
/* Just to add some interaction to the demo */

const w = document.getElementById("wrapper");
let x;

function toggle(event) {

  const d = document.getElementById("D");
  return d 
    ? 
      x = d.cloneNode() && w.removeChild(d) 
    : w.appendChild(x);
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}



.item {
  grid-column-start: span 2
}

.item:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(2),
.item:nth-child(n+4) {
  grid-column-start: auto;
}


/* Non-relevant CSS here: */

button {
  margin: 20px auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

#A { background: #7984f7 }
#B { background: #cb8af8 }
#C { background: #8cd4fb }
#D { background: #97f8d8 }

.item {
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="A" class="item">A</div>
  <div id="B" class="item">B</div>
  <div id="C" class="item">C</div>
  <div id="D" class="item">D</div>
</div>

<button onclick="toggle()">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use flexbox to do something similar instead of using a grid setup.
I personally find flexbox to be a much more useful/powerful tool in terms of making things responsive without breaking in ugly ways. It's easy to add responsive styles to modify it accordingly.

You could do something like:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item:first-of-type {
  width: 100%;
}
.item:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 100%;
}
.item:nth-of-type(3):last-of-type {
  width: 100%;
}
.item:nth-of-type(3) {
  width: 50%;
}
.item:nth-of-type(4) {
  width: 50%;
}
```

This way, if you have a 5th or 6th (or etc) items and you wanted their widths to vary depending on the number of elements, you could do a similar thing here. If you look at my demo, if you remove the 4th item, the 3rd item as the last element will have 100% width.

[CodePen rough example](https://codepen.io/erica_summers86/pen/QYPxVz)

Comment: Answers are even better when you don't have to go to another site to see them in action. Consider using [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to embed a runnable snippet here on Stack Overflow.